# Disallow fluid top to bottom height in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

How do I make the `$100` to have its own height? now it's fluid to the top and bottom. I'm able to make it vertical align using 'align-item' but it has fluid top to bottom height which is not I wanted.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <p>
      abc
    </p>
    <p>
      123
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    $100
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `align-items: center` to `wrap` element...